# How to fadeIn text in vegaswalk background gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i'm playing around with the vegas background script and would like to add a caption to each of the backgrounds using the "vegaswalk" function. all working fine but i would like to add a fadeIn on the div id="marketingText", is it possible? the text needs to fade in each time.

```
  $('body').bind('vegaswalk',
  function(e, bg, step) {
    if(step == 0) {
        $('#marketingText').text("new dialog title 1");
        }
    if(step == 1) {
        $('#marketingText').text("new dialog title some different text 2");
        }
    if(step == 2) {
        $('#marketingText').text("new dialog title more text 3");
        }
    if(step == 3) {
        $('#marketingText').text("new dialog title and some more 4");
        }
  }
);
```

i've tried the following

```
$('#marketingText').hide().fadeIn(3000).text("new dialog title 4");
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and let us know specifically what goes wrong.

Comment: Before anything!!! Do this: $('#marketingText').text("new dialog title " + (step + 1)); instead of the if statements

Comment: that doesn't work as the "new dialog title" part will change each time to, currently only there as example

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you tried? Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/n1u26aLu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like:

```
  var $mark= $('#marketingText');
  var textsArr = [ // Array of texts
    "new dialog title 1",
    "new dialog title some different text 2",
    "new dialog title more text 3",
    "new dialog title and some more 4"
  ];

  $('body').bind('vegaswalk', function(e, bg, step) {
    $mark.hide().text( textsArr[step] ).fadeIn(1000);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify most of this into 1 function:

```
$('body').bind('vegaswalk',
    function(e, bg, step) {
        $('#marketingText').text("new dialog title " + (step + 1)).fadeIn(3000);
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks but please see above as the text will change for each step as well

Answer (score 0):

thank @tymeJV

using your method and adding an array worked

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[ 0 ] = "new dialog title 1";
myArray[ 1 ] = "new dialog title 2";
myArray[ 2 ] = "new dialog title 3";
myArray[ 3 ] = "new dialog title 4";


$('body').bind('vegaswalk',
  function(e, bg, step) {
    $('#marketingText').text( myArray[ step ] ).hide().fadeIn(3000);
  }
);
```

Comment: Don't build Arrays that way... use simply `var arr = ["a","b","c"]` , also, if you care about performance cache your element `$('#marketingText')` into a Variable